# ¿Cómo crear un redirect para un post de tipo "product" en Wordpress usando add_rewrite_rule?

Tags: php, wordpress

¡Hola a todos! Tengo una página de wordpress donde tengo rewrite rules personalizados. Por ejemplo:

`add_rewrite_rule("([A-Za-z0-9-]*)/contacto$", "index.php?page_id=19", "top");`

Esto lo hago porque el sitio es multisitio y pueden haber páginas como **pagina.com/mexico/contacto** y **pagina.com/peru/contacto** y funciona perfectamente. Sin embargo, el sitio tiene "productos" los cuales se guardan con `post_type=products` en la base de datos. Si yo pongo en la url **pagina.com/index.php?page_id=400** me carga la página del producto que quiero. Por lo tanto agrgué el rewrite rule:

`add_rewrite_rule("([A-Za-z0-9-]*)/producto/objeto1$", "index.php?page_id=400", "top");`

Pero al cargarse la página, si acceso a **pagina.com/mexico/producto/objeto1** el producto no se carga. No sé si el hecho de que el `post_type` no sea `post` esté afectando. ¿Algún consejo de qué podría estar evitando que la página del producto se muestre y cómo solucionarlo? Los permalinks están puestos como "Post name". Proporcionaré cualquier información extra que necesiten.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: no se si serviría: 
add_rewrite_rule("([A-Za-z0-9-]*)/producto/objeto1$", "index.php?page_id=400&post_type=loquecorresponda", "top");

sustituyendo "loquecorresponda" por el nombre slug del post_type

Comment: Hola @Dr.Manhattan muchísimas gracias! Justamente eso faltaba, tuve que agregar el post_type y aparte el post_name (esto último es debido a que el plugin lo ocupaba) y retirar el page_id, con eso funcionó perfectamente! Me has solucionado la vida